# Python go one folder up?

Tags: python

**Nevermind i just printed the wrong thing, and it worked with `os.chdir("ImportFrom\\")`**

I bet this is a very basic thing, so googling it gives me bad result, since people see it as common knowledge :o

I just want my .py to read stuff in 1 folder up

```
C:/script/FOLDER/target.txt
C:/script/my.py
```

```
import os
print(cwd) #<--- STUPID ME FORGOT TO CHANGE THE VARIALBE, print print(os.getcwd()) instead!
os.chdir("\\FOLDER\\..")
print(cwd) #<--- STUPID ME FORGOT TO CHANGE THE VARIALBE, print print(os.getcwd()) instead!
```

always print:

```
C:/script/
C:/script/
```

Other combinations crash or same result. (Its not directly on C: its not a permission issue)

Hardcodeing the path already works, but what do i have to tell python to make the working directory the `import` Folder (name never changes). It would already help if you could tell me where i could find proper documentation of what \\ and ... actually does.

Sorry if its a stupid question, and thanks for reading it.

Comment: You can do: `os.chdir(os.pardir)`

Comment: To check the current directory use: `os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @bernie, I use os.pardir to get the parent directory. Example below from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-pardir-method-with-example/

```
import os  

# Current working directory 
path = os.getcwd() 
print("Current Directory:", path) 

# parent directory 
parent = os.path.join(path, os.pardir) 

# prints parent directory 
print("\nParent Directory:", os.path.abspath(parent))
```

Output:

> Current Directory: /home/geeks/Desktop/gfg
>
> Parent Directory: /home/geeks/Desktop

So now to change the working directory I use os.chdir.

```
import os

# Current working directory
path = os.getcwd()
print("Current Directory:", path)

# parent directory 
parent = os.path.join(path, os.pardir)
# Change to parent directory
os.chdir(parent)
# prints current directory 
print("New Current Directory:", os.getcwd())
```

> Current Directory: /home/geeks/Desktop/gfg
>
> New Current Directory: /home/geeks/Desktop

Answer (score 2):

You could use `pathlib` which is part of Python 3. No `pip` installation required as it is included.

```
from pathlib import Path
your_file = Path("C:/script/FOLDER/target.txt")
#get the parent directory with 
print(your_file.parent)
```

For reference, "one folder up" is typically referred to as the "parent directory"

You would find a lot of search results on this using that terminology. The current file/directory is referred to as the child.

Comment: Pathlib > os for path related stuff

Comment: Note that you can `.parent` several times, meaning `parent.parent` to go "two folders up"